# Running Total formula in Netsuite Saved Search is duplicating each row

Tags: sql, netsuite, partition-by, saved-searches

I am using the SUM OVER PARTITION formula in Netsuite transaction saved search to get the running total of item quantity.

SUM /* comment */ {quantity} OVER(PARTITION BY {item} ORDER BY {trandate} ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)

The formula works but it duplicates each row as shown below.
Each transaction # of the item appears twice here

Any advise on how can I correct this?

[image: Search formula and results]

[Search criteria](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXuHb.png)

Answer (score 0):

You don't show your Criteria tab, but I suspect you have not filtered by COGS Line.  Transactions affecting inventory movements typically include COGS Lines (unseen in the UI) which include the Item field, so they show up where you're filtering by Item.

Criteria Tab > Filter = COGS Line > Description = true

Comment: Only Inventory Asset account is selected. 
screenshot attached

Comment: I can't reproduce the described behavior from what you've shown.  Could you show the rest of your criteria?